# ProgressBar 10 секунд

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Подскажите как заставить крутиться ProgressBar n секунд и затем перейти на новый activity ???

Comment: Он разве не крутиться до момента, когда его не остановят?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется все проще чем на первый взгляд. Когда вам нужно вы запускаете `ProgressBar` и дальше через `Handler` переходите на другую активность:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourNewClass.class);
    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
   //переход через 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

Так же здесь в теле функции Run вы можете указать остановку `ProgressBar` но мне кажется что при переходе на другую активность он будет останавливаться.